# asp.net row_created get text of an inserted cell of the first row

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am working on an asp.net project.

I am using a database and a gridview.
I want to get the name of the first cell of each gridviewrow when it is created.
Why is this not working?

```
protected void CustomersGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Response.Write(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text of first column of each row of a gridview ,then use the code as follows:-

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    Response.Write(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
}
```